# The deepest nested writable folder?

Tags: linux

Hi guys I need to find the deepest nested writable folder:

I write this command: `find . -type d -printf '%d:%p\n' | sort -n | tail -1`

But how to add the condition "Is this folder writable"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
find . -type d -writable -printf '%d:%p\n' | sort -n | tail -1
```

`man find` said :

> -writable
>
> Matches  files  which  are  writable.  This takes into account access control lists and other permissions artefacts which the
>   -perm test ignores.  This test makes use of the access(2)
>                  system call, and so can be fooled by NFS servers which do UID mapping (or root-squashing), since many systems implement
>   access(2) in the client's kernel and so cannot make use of  the
>                  UID mapping information held on the server.

This works for dirs too.